# Logic of creating sql tables -

Tags: sql

When is it better to create a few SQL tables, rather then one large table? (assuming it is possible to store all data in one table)

What are the advanteges and disadvanteges of one table over a few?

Comment: A rule of thumb: If you don't have a good reason to keep everyghint on a single table, don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general rule it depends on what you want to store and how to you want/need to access it.

You have to think on use cases and what you need to do with the data and optimize the design accordingly.